# How can I navigate to a specific page in an Appium test when using the Page Object Model design pattern?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I've got my Appium tests running smoothly for my Android app. Coded using Maven and Kotlin. My app only has one LAUNCHER activity which is my SplashScreenActivity.

Currently, I have a baseTest class that provides OS-level functionality, such things as `waitForElement` or `swipeScreen(dir: Direction, amount: Int)`.

Then I have an `AppTest` class that extends that and provides some App-specific functionality. Most importantly is a function called `startApp()`, which starts my app, logins in as my test user and navigates to my home screen. Each test for a specific UI then extends this AppTest class and creates its own `getToUI` function, which simply runs the startApp function and then automates a few other button clicks to get to the specific UI to be tested.

Now I'm trying to add the Page Object Model design pattern to my tests. How should I implement this sort of navigation to the UI to be tested? Should I put the code to navigate to the page in each page class's init? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: So you are trying to do something like having `someElement.click()`. With some element containing the identifier and the logic behind the click?

Comment: no, I'm asking how do you get to the page in the first place. In my app you have to login first and maybe click 5 buttons to get to the page that I want to test. None of the examples I've seen explain how you're supposed to get to the UI page you want to test. The examples I've seen just say "create a new LoginPage(Driver)" now start clicking on elements. How is my app supposed to get to the LoginPage to begin with before I can run the Appium test?

Comment: Are you doing this in Java or C#?

Comment: This is in Kotlin as I'm testing and Android app. Once I get this working I'll attempt to get the IOS app working as well

Comment: Either way, what you could do is create an abstract class with a method Login(). This would bring you to the same entry point for all your tests. Then all your tests simply inherit the abstract class. If you are doing this in Java with a TestNG combo I could go into more detail.

Comment: I am not versed in Kotlin at all, however what I suppose you could at the very least do then is create a class with a static method that does the login for you - the caveat being you would have to call it every test. If you can inherit it you could do all of this in the abstract class constructor. So your `new MyTest()` would call `GenericTest()` as base/super and the GenericTest base constructor would guide it through the steps of doing the login.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking to optimise the way to navigate to a page while testing a specific UI, I would recommend using the [Appium's start activity](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/activity/start-activity/) command, provided that UI is not a fragment.

There are ways of faking login functionality i.e. generating a test authentication token and adding it to the HTTP headers or adding the authentication cookie and sending it along the HTTP request but that is more specific to how authentication is implemented in your project.

In a BDD style test it should look like:

```
given: a user and user is logged in
when: user opens SOME PAGE
then: SOME VALIDATION HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

Page Object Model is just an abstraction. Its up to you to decide level of granularity: it could be app fragment, screen on UI, part of the screen on UI, etc.

You can also have a single global `Actions` class to to wrap general actions, e.g. launch/re-start app, launch activity, put app in background, etc.

Assuming that you should login one time, and then to speedup things you will just re-start activity, it may look like it:

```
before:

LoginScreen loginScreen = Actions.launchApp(); // should load login screen
HomeScreen home = loginScreen.loginWithValidUser();
```

```
beforeEach:

HomeScreen homeScreen = Actions.launchHomeActivity() // no need to login, it is cached, just restart activity; maybe you need to make server API call to flush user data?
```

```
test

UserProfileScreen userScreen = homeScreen.openUserProfile()
userScreen.changePassword(newPassword)
userScreen.save()
Actions.navigateBack()

homeScreen....
```

Still it is up to you to return PO instance during navigation to other screen. It is fine just to have static functions, personal taste and usability.